# Azure Project - Need guidance

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am working on a small introductory Azure project where I need  to distribute documents among the worker roles  in a load  balanced manner. 
I am a  beginner in both ASP .NET and  azure. 
I would like some ideas on how  to  do  this with azure/resources that will help me do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the documents into Azure blob storage an put a work item in a queue. The workers would pull an entry from the queue and delete it while they process the document. Just keep in mind that if a worker fails, you'll want some way to re-queue the work. You could do this by reknewing the lock on the queue item before deleting it, or by using another store, say a table entry that you can check perioically and use to requeue failed items.

Comment: Why not rely on the automatic re-queuing feature whereby if the entry isn't deleted within a defined time period, it is automatically re-queued?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the  answer. So I actually want  to know how to  create multiple worker roles in azure. Should every worker role have a queue containing pointers to the documents in the blob ?

Comment: Your solution will contain only one Worker Role. But in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file, you'll configure the number of *instances* of that role to run. The role will simply read a message from the queue, process it and read the next message. In this way, as long as there's work to process, each instance will be busy. And as I pointed out in my post, the record in the queue should point to the document in the blob (the document will have a URL; you can use that).

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks. So as a starting point, I did this. Read all files in a directory and make them into blobs and  get reference and store  it in queue as message. I tried running this and got deployment error due to incorrect NTFS permission in web.config. Can you pl tell me how to rectify this error ?

Comment: also can the instance count be set  dynamically depending on the work ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you start by reading up on Azure Queue Storage ([Queue Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179363.aspx)). By inserting messages into a queue, worker roles can take work from that queue as they are able. The size of an entry on a queue is limited to 8KB, so I'd recommend that you put that actual document in SQL Azure (if your application is using it) or Azure BLOB Storage ([Blob Storage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135733.aspx)) and post a message on the queue that contains a reference to the stored document.

Comment: Hi Steven Thanks.. I will look into this and implement it and get back in case of  errors/other problems.

Answer (score 0):

A good learning resource to start with is the [Developing Application for the Cloud](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966499.aspx) guide and a sample app from [Microsoft patterns & practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/practices).